# Calling __new__ when making a subclass of tuple

Tags: python, class, subclass, pyspark, subclassing

In Python, when subclassing tuple, the `__new__` function is called with self as an argument. For example, here is a paraphrased version of PySpark's `Row` class:

```
class Row(tuple):
    def __new__(self, args):
        return tuple.__new__(self, args)
```

But `help(tuple)` shows no `self` argument to `__new__`:

```
  __new__(*args, **kwargs) from builtins.type
      Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature.
```

and `help(type)` just says the same thing:

```
__new__(*args, **kwargs)
      Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature.
```

So how does `self` get passed to `__new__` in the `Row` class definition?

- Is it via `*args`?
- Does `__new__` have some subtlety where its signature can change with context?
- Or, is the documentation mistaken?

Is it possible to view the source of `tuple.__new__` so I can see the answer for myself?

My question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304) because in that question, all discussion refers to `__new__` methods that explicitly have `self` or `cls` as first argument. I'm trying to understand

1. Why the `tuple.__new__` method does not have `self` or `cls` as first argument.
2. How I might go about examining the source code of the tuple class, to see for myself what's really going on.

Follow-up: Moderators closed this old question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new). But it's not a duplicate. Look at the accepted answer on this question and note how little overlap it has with the answers in the claimed duplicate, in terms of the information provided.

Comment: The very documentation that you quote says that this is not the full accurate signature.

Comment: I can see that, but help(type) does not provide any more information, just the same signature and the same comment about accurate signature. So I'm still mystified.

Comment: First argument of `__new__` is not instance, but class. Thus, it's usually named `cls`, not `self`. Under the hood, `tuple() == tuple.__new__(tuple)`, and `tuple(iterable) == tuple.__new__(tuple, iterable)`.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) say that `object.__new__(cls[, ...])` is "Called to create a new instance of class `cls`. `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) _that takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument_."  (emphasis mine) — The value it returns will become the `self` passed on to other methods (unlike for example `__init__()` which doesn't have a return value).

Comment: [How is tuple implemented in CPython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135542/how-is-tuple-implemented-in-cpython)

Comment: Piecing these comments together, it appears the answer is that `cls` is being passed via `*args`, since `object.__new__` must always be passed `cls`. Thanks @martineau and @GingerPlusPlus.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The correct signature of `tuple.__new__`

Functions and types implemented in C often can't be inspected, and their signature always look like that one.

The correct signature of `tuple.__new__` is:

```
__new__(cls[, sequence])
```

For example:

```
>>> tuple.__new__(tuple)
()
>>> tuple.__new__(tuple, [1, 2, 3])
(1, 2, 3)
```

Not surprisingly, this is exactly as calling `tuple()`, except for the fact that you have to repeat `tuple` twice.

---

### The first argument of `__new__`

Note that the first argument of `__new__` is always the class, not the instance. In fact, the role of `__new__` is to create and return the new instance.

The special method `__new__` is a static method.

I'm saying this because in your `Row.__new__` I can see `self`: while the name of the argument is not important (except when using keyword arguments), beware that `self` will be `Row` or a subclass of `Row`, not an instance. The general convention is to name the first argument `cls` instead of `self`.

---

### Back to your questions

> So how does `self` get passed to `__new__` in the `Row` class definition?

When you call `Row(...)`, Python automatically calls `Row.__new__(Row, ...)`.

> - Is it via `*args`?

You can write your `Row.__new__` as follows:

```
class Row(tuple):
    def __new__(*args, **kwargs):
        return tuple.__new__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works and there's nothing wrong about it. It's very useful if you don't care about the arguments.

> - Does `__new__` have some subtlety where its signature can change with context?

No, the only special thing about `__new__` is that it is a static method.

> - Or, is the documentation mistaken?

I'd say that it is incomplete or ambiguous.

> - Why the `tuple.__new__` method does not have `self` or `cls` as first argument.

It does have, it's just not appearing on `help(tuple.__new__)`, because often that information is not exposed by functions and methods implemented in C.

> - How I might go about examining the source code of the `tuple` class, to see for myself what's really going on.

The file you are looking for is [`Objects/tupleobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dcced3bd22fe/Objects/tupleobject.c). Specifically, you are interested in the [`tuple_new()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dcced3bd22fe/Objects/tupleobject.c#l633) function:

```
static char *kwlist[] = {"sequence", 0};
/* ... */
if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "|O:tuple", kwlist, &arg))
```

Here `"|O:tuple"` means: the function is called "tuple" and it accepts one optional argument (`|` delimits optional arguments, `O` stands for a Python object). The optional argument may be set via the keyword argument `sequence`.

---

### About `help(type)`

For the reference, you were looking at the documentation of `type.__new__`, while you should have stopped at the first four lines of `help(type)`:

In the case of `__new__()` the correct signature is the signature of `type()`:

```
class type(object)
 |  type(object_or_name, bases, dict)
 |  type(object) -> the object's type
 |  type(name, bases, dict) -> a new type
```

But this is not relevant, as `tuple.__new__` has a different signature.

---

### Remember `super()`!

Last but not least, try to use `super()` instead of calling `tuple.__new__()` directly.

Comment: what if I want to redefine its parameter? \n tuple2 inherted from tuple

Comment: What if I want to redefine its parameters?
tuple2 inhert from tuple.It act like:
tuple2(2) == (0,0) 、 tuple2(5) == (0,0,0,0,0)

however tuple.__new__ accept only iterable rather than int.
so __new__ makes all the evaluation and we can do nothing in __init__

Comment: _(:з」∠)_don't know how to make a line break

Comment: @喵喵喵 you can define your own `__new__` like this: `def __new__(cls, size): return super().__new__(cls, (0,) * size)`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini If I write (0,)* size in __new__ .  I assigned it an default value. Since tuple is immutable, no further assignment can be made.

Comment: I mean, if I modify a immutable subclass, all assignments shall be made in '__new__' ?

Comment: @喵喵喵 as you said, tuples are immutable. If you want something that can be changed, use list or array or define your own class: you're not forced to inherit from builtin types, in fact I would discourage it if you're going to change the semantics drastically