# Is it faster to iterate a small list within an any() statement?

Tags: python, list, caching, optimization, iteration

Consider the following operation in the limit of low length iterables,

```
d = (3, slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None))

In [215]: %timeit any([type(i) == slice for i in d])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 695 ns per loop

In [214]: %timeit any(type(i) == slice for i in d)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 929 ns per loop
```

Setting as a `list` is 25% faster than using a generator expression?

Why is this the case as setting as a `list` is an extra operation.

Note: In both runs I obtained the warning: *`The slowest run took 6.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached`* I

### Analysis

In this particular test, `list()` structures are faster up to a length of `4` from which the generator has increased performance.

The red line shows where this event occurs and the black line shows where both are equal in performance.

[image]
The code takes about 1min to run on my MacBook Pro by utilising all the cores:

```
import timeit, pylab, multiprocessing
import numpy as np

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
g = manager.list([])
l = manager.list([])

rng = range(1,16) # list lengths
max_series = [3,slice(None, None, None)]*rng[-1] # alternate array types
series = [max_series[:n] for n in rng]

number, reps = 1000000, 5
def func_l(d):
    l.append(timeit.repeat("any([type(i) == slice for i in {}])".format(d),repeat=reps, number=number))
    print "done List, len:{}".format(len(d))
def func_g(d):
    g.append(timeit.repeat("any(type(i) == slice for i in {})".format(d), repeat=reps, number=number))
    print "done Generator, len:{}".format(len(d))

p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=min(16,rng[-1])) # optimize for 16 processors
p.map(func_l, series) # pool list
p.map(func_g, series) # pool gens

ratio = np.asarray(g).mean(axis=1) / np.asarray(l).mean(axis=1)
pylab.plot(rng, ratio, label='av. generator time / av. list time')
pylab.title("{} iterations, averaged over {} runs".format(number,reps))
pylab.xlabel("length of iterable")
pylab.ylabel("Time Ratio (Higher is worse)")
pylab.legend()
lt_zero = np.argmax(ratio<1.)
pylab.axhline(y=1, color='k')
pylab.axvline(x=lt_zero+1, color='r')
pylab.ion() ; pylab.show()
```

Comment: I thought this was non-trivial? Apparently down voters disagree? Is the question unclear? Why is the question in particular too broad? Is it not highly specific to the example given?

Comment: I was one of the down voters. I down voted it (before any edit) because, it seemed lack of research to me. But apparently it's not. So +1.

Comment: @salmanwahed Thanks for the feedback, it is much appreciated as I strive to asks decent questions and provide good answers on the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch is the size of the items you are applying `any` on. Repeat the same process on a larger dataset:

```
In [2]: d = ([3] * 1000) + [slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None)]*1000

In [3]: %timeit any([type(i) == slice for i in d])
1000 loops, best of 3: 736 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit any(type(i) == slice for i in d)
1000 loops, best of 3: 285 µs per loop
```

Then, using a `list` (loading all the items into memory) becomes much slower, and the generator expression plays out better.

Comment: I am only dealing with lists up to length of 10. Why in this lower limit is this the case?

Comment: For a length of 10 (or rather 3 in your post), the tuple can easily be cached and reused across all iterations of the timer, whereas the generator version will always be lazy.

Comment: any link to docs explaining this behaviour / key terms to look up? - I should note I tried searching the obvious `cashing list iteration` etc. and didn't obtain anything useful

Comment: Check this: [When is not a good time to use python generators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245792/when-is-not-a-good-time-to-use-python-generators) and this: [How is tuple implemented in CPython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135542/how-is-tuple-implemented-in-cpython)

Comment: You may be interested in the update: Accordingly, lists are faster in this test scenario up to a length of 4, from which generators are drastically faster!