Why does Python treat 1.0j as 1j as the same?
I'm beginning to learn about Python and am starting to understand the importance between integers and floats and how they are different objects. For example, the integer 1 is not the same as the float 1.0. I am confused because Python does not do this for complex numbers.
If I define a complex number as z1 = 1.0 + 2.0j and print it, the output will be (1+2j). I would have assumed that the output will be (1.0+2.0j), but this is not the case. Furthermore, when I define another complex number z2 = 1 + 2j and test whether these two variables reference the same object, they do. So what is going on here?

"whether these two variables reference the same object, they do" - Actually, they don't. z1 and z2 have the same value, but they are distinct objects.

@ThierryLathuille Maybe in your Python, the way you tried it. They were the same object when I tried it.

Furthermore, when I define another complex number z2 = 1 + 2j and test whether these two variables reference the same object, they do I just tried this in my local python 3.13 interpreter on my windows machine and it shows they are not the same object. However I tried it in replit.com and it shows they are the same object.  z1 = 1.0 + 2.0j; z2 = 1 + 2j; print(z1 is z2); print(id(z1)); print(id(z2));

output in my local interpreter:
False



id(z1)
3131138235920
id(z2)
3131138235856



output in python repl on replit.com:
True
139920561458000
139920561458000

@16171413 Now do it locally but on one line (or in a script you then run).

@no comment in a script, both objects are the same

z1 == z2 test for value equality, whereas the construct z1 is z2 tests to see if they are the same object (in memory). print ( z1 == z2 ) gives True whereas print(z1 is z2) gives False

@ticktalk Not true. Read the previous comments.

@nocomment, fair enough. this behaviour is due optimisation when running as a script. To 'ensure' they are distinct objects, then define them as such to enforce ie: 'z1 = complex(1.0, 2.0)
z2 = complex(1,2)'' shouldavoid optimisation and create distinct objects

ah i found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49327911/16668765 that's quoting id docs: "This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value."

@folengateis Are you responding to something? It's not clear why you're saying that.

@nocomment yes i'm answering to this question. but i can't add much to the answer i'm linking to and i don't understand everything (have no clue of how to change the lifetime). so i can't write a good answer. i also think it's a dupe now

@folengateis, ...I don't see how that answers the question as currently posed, unless the OP used id() to compare identity, and there's no indication that they did.

Complex numbers representation
In Python the real and imaginary parts of a complex number are stored internally using the float data type. You can check that with this simple code
x = 3 + 2j
y = 4.0 + 5.0j

print(type(x.real), type(x.imag))
print(type(y.real), type(y.imag))

and the result is
<class 'float'> <class 'float'>
<class 'float'> <class 'float'>

That's why 3 + 2j == 3.0 + 2.0j is True.
Omitting the trailing zeros is a convention for representing complex numbers not only in Python as trailing zeros are a redundant information and are omitted for better readability and conciseness.
Object interning
Python uses a technique called object interning to optimize memory usage and speed up comparisons.
When an immutable object is found it checks if an identical object already exists in memory and if it does it assigns the variable to the existing object.That's why the two variables reference the same object as interned objects are essentially the same object in memory.
z1 = 1.0 + 2.0j
z2 = 1 + 2j

print(z1 is z2)
print(id(z1), id(z2))


True
139931293956080 139931293956080


The OP was referring to "the same object", not to equality. Unless they're new enough to Python to not understand the difference between equality and identity, I read this as a question about interning.

When you compile it as a script, the compiler can intern the objects and make them the same object. When you enter each statement separately in an REPL, there's no interning.

There's still interning within each line.

"When an immutable object is found it checks if an identical object already exists in memory and if it does it assigns the variable to the existing object." - Misleadingly generalized. For example, z1 is --z1 gives me False.
