# What makes python tuples immutable. How are they implemented in the memory?

Tags: python, tuples

I want to know how are python tuples made immutable, in the sense that how are they implemented in the memory such that we cannot change their values?

A python list `in general` is implemented as a dynamic array and its values can be modified at a particular index by directly accessing the index and assigning a different value. Tuples are immutable, but what conditions make them immutable? Why can we not change their values, is it like the memory elements are locked with extra conditions over a list which makes it a tuple?

Also

A string is immutable, it makes sense why it is immutable as its state cannot be changed. A string `p` will always represent `p`. But what's with tuple?

Any definitions above are very general and I am not sure what extra conditions or cases python takes into consideration when I said `python list is implemented as a dynamic array`.

Please suggest how the implementation works and also any sources where I can read more about this.

Edit: I already saw this thread : [How is tuple implemented in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135542/how-is-tuple-implemented-in-cpython) But I cannot understand it properly. I need a more simplified explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is tuple implemented in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135542/how-is-tuple-implemented-in-cpython)

Comment: @KentShikama No, I have edited my post. Thanks

Comment: Can anyone explain why is there a downvote on this question? I will modify it if it's unclear.

Comment: "with respect to Python itself directly" - What do you mean by this? CPython is the reference implementation of Python. I could create my own Python implementation that uses `[insert crazy data structure here]` to implement tuples but I'm assuming you're not interested in that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing special about the implementation or memory layout of tuples that makes them immutable. They're immutable because they just don't *have* any mutator operations.

Lists are mutable because the `list` class implements operations like `append` and `__setitem__` that mutate lists. Such operations have to be deliberately included in the implementation; they don't come into existence automatically. If `list` didn't have mutator operations, lists would be immutable too.

At the level of the C implementation, the C code that implements tuples has to be able to write to a tuple's memory, and at that level, the data structures are mutable. The interface the implementation presents to Python code is immutable, though.

You can't do the same with a class you implement in Python because you can't get a firm separation between implementation and interface. Such a separation arises automatically when implementing a Python class in C due to the design of the Python C API, but without anything like a `private` access modifier, you can't do the same in Python.

Comment: Ok, that made sense! It is just how it is defined in its implementation, there are no `mutator operations` defined on them so we cannot use them, which makes a tuple immutable. Alright! 

Also, it means that if I want to create an immutable class of my own in Python then that's not possible. I have to use an existing immutable data structure to do that.