# Does Python's runtime really cache tuples of size 1-20?

Tags: python, caching, tuples

I'm reading *[High Performance Python](https://www.amazon.ca/High-Performance-Python-Performant-Programming/dp/1449361595)* by Micha Gorelick. In chapter 3 on tuples vs lists he claims that tuples of size 1-20 are cached by the Python runtime. I did not find an answer to this on the first page of a Google search, nor [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple). Can someone provide an official Python source that confirms this claim?

**Quotes from book**

> "Tuples are cached by the Python runtime, which means that we don't need to talk to the kernal to reserve memory every time we want to use one."

> "For tuples of sizes 1-20, however, when they are no longer in use the space isn't immediately given back to the system, but rather saved for future use."

Comment: There is a cache of tuples (and afaik lists) used for literals, and the *cache* might match the size of 20. Caching "tuples of size 1-20" seems excessive, as there are possibly tons of them. Can you cite the claim for those of us without access to the book?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Okay, I'll add the exact quotes soon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is tuple implemented in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135542/how-is-tuple-implemented-in-cpython)

Comment: It doesn't directly answer my question because my question requires an official Python source, however it indirectly provided links to what I was looking for.

Comment: Since this is an implementation detail of CPython, there likely is no official Python source.

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c) of the implementation detail is an acceptable source.